# Firebase multi-location update overwriting instead of updating value

Tags: firebase

I'm currently have the exact same issue as outlined in this article:

https://medium.com/@danbroadbent/firebase-multi-path-updates-updating-denormalized-data-in-multiple-locations-b433565fd8a5

Currently the Firebase single node `.update()` function will not overwrite other same level child nodes.

However when using multi-location `ref.update()` all other child nodes in the same level are overwriten, essentially acting as a `.set()` function.

Is there someway I can actually run multi-location `.update()` without overwriting all same level child nodes?

Comment: Please include representative code and data in your question.

Comment: I have the same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this github issue: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/313

One possible workaround would be defining each field you want to update as separate update, and update it as a part of atomic update, that way you would actually update each individual field needed to be updated?

```
var companiesPath = 'companies/company_name';
var usersPath = 'users/user_nickname';

var data = {};
data[companiesPath] = 'Best Company Name';
data[usersPath] = 'John';

firebase.update(data);
```

So you can't update the complete object, you need to target the individual fields of that object. I just tested it and this works...

Comment: Yea I used the same method as a workaround. The downside is if you have lots of nested nodes in the target node then you need to manually enter each one and their values otherwise they'll be deleted

Comment: You should try to minimize the nesting of data, keep the firebase database as flat as possible...