# Firebase Multipath updates overwrites instead of update children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase real-time database in my Android app. For data normalization purposes, I'm saving Player's data to multiple paths.
When I save it to each path separately all works fine. But I tried to save the data using Multiple-Path update and then instead of updating existing children, this overwrites existing data (like in setValue). I read about this phenomenon somewhere but I can't get it to work as it should.

Here is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
public void createPlayerInFirebaseDatabse(String playerId, FirebasePlayerEntity firebasePlayerEntity, final ICreateUser listener) {

    Log.e(TAG, "DBHelper.createPlayerInFirebaseDatabase");

    Map<String, Object> player = new HashMap<>();
    player.put(playerId, firebasePlayerEntity);

    Map<String, Object> isPlayerIn = new HashMap<>();
    isPlayerIn.put(playerId, true);

    Map<String, Object> playerUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    playerUpdates.put("players/", player);
    playerUpdates.put("leagues/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getLeagueCode() + "/playersIds/", isPlayerIn);
    playerUpdates.put("teams/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getTeam() + "/playersIds", isPlayerIn);
    databaseReference.updateChildren(playerUpdates)

            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "DBHelper.createPlayerInFirebaseDatabase: onSuccess");
                listener.onSuccess();
            } else {
                listener.onError(ErrorConsts.ERROR_CODE_DB_WRITING_FAILED);
            }
        }
    });
```

It only updates the data (not overwriting) when I save data separately to each path, like this:

```
databaseReference.child(REF_PLAYERS).updateChildren(player);
databaseReference.child(REF_LEAGUES + "/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getLeagueCode() + "/" + REF_PLAYERS_IDS).updateChildren(isPlayerIn);
databaseReference.child(REF_TEAMS + "/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getTeam() + "/" + REF_PLAYERS_IDS).updateChildren(isPlayerIn)
```

I found this topic on javascript [Firebase multi-location update overwriting instead of updating value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626489/firebase-multi-location-update-overwriting-instead-of-updating-value)
but I was wondering if anyone experienced it on Android and managed to solve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multi-location update loops over each key in the `Map` that you pass in, and the performs a `setValue` on that path. It does not do a "deep merge", so anything at any specific key in your map will be replaced. For this reason, you need to make sure that the paths in your map are to the exact data that you want to replace.

Right now your map keys point one level to high. For example your maps says to update `players` with `$playeruid/<playerEntity>`. This means that you're replacing everything under `players` with the data for the new player, which is not what you want. What you instead should do is tell Firebase to update `players/$playeruid` to `<playerEntity>`, so making `$playeruid` part of the path/key.

In code:

```
Map<String, Object> playerUpdates = new HashMap<>();
playerUpdates.put("players/" + playerId, firebasePlayerEntity);
playerUpdates.put("leagues/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getLeagueCode() + "/playersIds/" + playerId, true);
playerUpdates.put("teams/" + firebasePlayerEntity.getTeam() + "/playersIds/" + playerId, true);
databaseReference.updateChildren(playerUpdates)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! now everything works as it should. I appreciate your help:)